# Percona Pmm helm upgrade failed: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: did not find expected key

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, percona

Trying to update our percona pmm instance ingress values and this error is getting thrown:

**Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on pmm/templates/ingress.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: did not find expected key**

I tried both with manual line by line commands as well as applying a values.yaml file:

```
helm upgrade pmm percona/pmm \
  --set ingress.enabled=true \
  --set ingress.nginxInc=true \
  --set ingress.ingressClassName=testprivate \
  --set ingress.hosts[0].host=pmm-tst-test.test-private.com \
  --set ingress.hosts[0].paths={} \
  --set ingress.tls[0].secretName=pmm-certificate
```

As well as the values.yaml:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  nginxInc: true
  annotations: {}
    # Add specific annotations here if needed
  community:
    annotations: {}
    # Add annotations for community-managed ingress here if needed
  ingressClassName: "testprivate"
  hosts:
    - host: pmm-tst-test.test-hos.com
      paths: []
  pathType: Prefix
  tls:
    - secretName: pmm-certificates
```

Pulled down the chart to grab the context for line 14 on ingress.yaml (line 14 in bold):

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $serviceName := .Values.service.name -}}
{{- $servicePort := (index $.Values.service.ports 1).port  -}}
{{- $ingressPathType := .Values.ingress.pathType -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ include "pmm.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "pmm.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
**{{- if or .Values.ingress.annotations .Values.ingress.nginxInc }}**
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml .Values.ingress.annotations | nindent 4 }}
    {{- if .Values.ingress.nginxInc }}
    nginx.org/ssl-services: {{ $serviceName }}-grpc
    nginx.org/grpc-services: {{ $serviceName }}-grpc
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

At wits ends here, any idea what im missing? Ive confirmed the secret exists, I have an nginx ingress controller deployed, and ive been able to alter all other values for the instance besides this one? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

The issue was that i had both ingress and nginx set to true. I had an nginx ingress controller placed in front of it, however because i also had the ingress value set to "true" it was expecting further configuration for the default ingress, hence the error message about a missing key. Setting it to false while keeping nginx true resolved it.

```
ingress:
  enabled: false
  nginxInc: true
  annotations: {}
```